# How to take full page screenshot using AShot library through Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, screenshot, ashot

I tried the below code for taking full page screenshot. But only the visible area is captured,

```
public void Fullscreen (WebDriver driver) 
{
    try {
        final Screenshot screenshot = new AShot().shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(1000)).takeScreenshot(driver);
        final BufferedImage image = screenshot.getImage();
        ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File("D:\\" + "AShot_BBC_Entire.png"));           
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

While working with *Selenium Java Client v3.14.0*, *ChromeDriver v2.41*, *Chrome v 68.0* using **ashot-1.4.4.jar** here is an example to take the *complete page screenshot* both horizontally and vertically using **ChromeDriver** and **aShot Library** of the *url* `https://jquery.com/`:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import java.io.File;
  import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.AShot;
  import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.Screenshot;
  import ru.yandex.qatools.ashot.shooting.ShootingStrategies;

  public class ashot_CompletePage {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

          System.setProperty("god.bless.you", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
          ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
          options.addArguments("start-maximized");
          options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
          options.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); 
          WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options);
          driver.get("https://jquery.com/");
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("jQuery"));
          Screenshot myScreenshot = new AShot().shootingStrategy(ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(100)).takeScreenshot(driver);
          ImageIO.write(myScreenshot.getImage(),"PNG",new File("./Screenshots/elementScreenshot.png"));
          driver.quit();
      }
  }
  ```
- Screenshots:

[image: screenshot]

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion in [How to take screenshot with Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/how-to-take-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver/55120087#55120087)

Comment: I'm new to selenium, I need the same code you've written here. I stuck at running your code. It shows import error. I resolved all import statements except selenium.webdriver i.e., `import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;`. CAn you help me where can I get this package?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't create an ImageOutputStream!
 at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1551)
 at WorldAirfaresTests.ashot_CompletePage.main(ashot_CompletePage.java:28)

Comment: @JustinLambert Let us discuss this in [Selenium Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium)

Comment: Visiting this a few years later, it would be seen as better to use driver.close() than driver.quit() (until the end of your whole program)

Answer (score 3):

Want to add answer in case when you don't know what kind of screen is used. (retina or not)

In this case you need find devicePixelRatio of browser window:

```
Object output = ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return window.devicePixelRatio");
String value = String.valueOf(output);
float windowDPR = Float.parseFloat(value);
```

Then you can use ShootingStrategy with scaling;

```
ShootingStrategy shootingStrategy = ShootingStrategies.viewportPasting(ShootingStrategies.scaling(windowDPR), 100)
```

Comment: It seems like latest versions of Ashot do not recognize the `int 100` parameter. I had to edit the code to:

`ShootingStrategy shootingStrategy = ShootingStrategies.scaling(windowDPR);`